# How to move a StackPanel in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

I would like to move a `StackPanel` horizontally when the user clicks a button.  I'm implementing `DoubleAnimation` with `TargetName` and `TargetProperty`.  But, I don't know which `TargetProperty` to use.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you put the `StackPanel` inside a `Canvas` you can achieve this behavior by setting the `Canvas.X` and `Canvas.Y` properties. Alternatively you could animate the `Margin` of the `StackPanel` by using `ThicknessAnimation`. Check out [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c190ea37-a9bc-45a9-afa8-06a06388a64f) for a similar request.

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be a [`TranslateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx) applied to the [`RenderTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) of the StackPanel. The `TargetProperty` path for the animation then would be `RenderTransform.X`.

Comment: TranslateTransform is probably the best way indeed.